# SSRS Report Can't view by my BI Team mate

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I created SSRS report project to share with the team. Since I created that Report project and I can create report and preview and upload to Reporting Server. I give my BI team mate all admin access to reporting server. My team mate can add report, upload report but can't preview mine or their report. What might be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permission issue with the data source. The permissions for Report Server are different than the permissions needed to access the database that the data is in.

Have the other user go to the report data source. If you use a shared datasource, check it out in the folder it was deployed to (`http://xxxdasql01/Report Server/Data Sources/` in the below example). If it is Embedded, go to the Properties of the report.

Test the data source connection. I would guess he doesn't have permission to the database it uses and will get an error.